# Picklist value present in global valueset but not in objects

Tags: dependent-picklist, global-picklist

I have a global valueSet named position. It has 17 values like

> Top 1, Top 2, Top 3, ..., Top 40, Top 1 vec, Top 6 vec, Top 10 vec

This valueSet is used on 4 fields on 3 objects : Product2 and 2 custom.
The first value, `Top 1`, used to be `Top position` but I changed it. I can't remember if I deleted/recreated it or if I just edited it.

Since then, it doesn't appear anymore in my picklists. If I try to set the value via DML, I have an error : `Incorrect value for restricted picklist : Top 1`. (real message is in french).

I also have field dependencies but deleting it didn't change anything.

I double checked that the value is active, in the interface and in the meta xml, it is  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GlobalValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customValue>
        <fullName>Top 1</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Top 1</label>
    </customValue>
    <customValue>
        <fullName>Top 2</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Top 2</label>
    </customValue>
...
```

Even the field dependecy looks ok on gui and xml :

```
... 
<type>Picklist</type>
<valueSet>
    <controllingField>Bloc__c</controllingField>
    <restricted>true</restricted>
    <valueSetName>Position</valueSetName>
    <valueSettings>
        <controllingFieldValue>Nouvelles ventes</controllingFieldValue>
        ...
        <valueName>Top 1</valueName>
    </valueSettings>
    ...
```

It really looks like a bug, I'm stuck , if I need to delete fields, dependencies, and global value set and then recreate all that, It will take hours...

Any idea welcome :)

Comment: Do you have Record Types on your objects? This could be something to check out.

Comment: I posted my question thinking, "hopefully Master Sfdcfox will answer it" :). I found before I read your comment -but after you wrote it- but thanks again, If you want to post an answer I'll mark it as best.

Comment: It's not a problem. You found it yourself, you can certainly have the credit. It's not like I need the points, after all!

Comment: I'll get you a coffee on https://www.buymeacoffee.com/sfdcfox ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem, then I saw sfdcfox did before me, once again :

I simply forgot to check this box :
[image: Value wasn't added to recordtypes]

That's why, as found @sfdcfox, the value wasn't available in my picklists.
I just have to edit recordtypes picklists and all will be ok.